# Pairwise censoring for survival analysis in a 1:x propensity-score matched sample

Tags: survival, propensity-scores

Take e.g. an observational study sample where subjects have varying follow-up lengths. We want to compare two treatments, *A* (intervention treatment; n=100) & *B* (control treatment; n=500), and see if there is a difference in the occurence of event X during follow-up.

Propensity-score matching is applied to create comparable groups on important confounders (nearest-neighbour matching, in a 1:3 ratio, caliper 0.1).

Time-to-event on matched weighted-data is analysed using Cox regression.

Since differences exist in follow-up time for every subject, pairwise censoring to account for attrition bias is desirable. **But, how would one go about doing this since every subject from the *treatment group A* is matched to multiple subject from *treatment group B*?**

Studies applying 1:x propensity score matching as well as pairwise censoring generally say something along the lines of "follow-up in each matched pair is determined as the shorter of the two patient follow-up periods (pairwise censoring) to mitigate
attrition bias", which I find a bit confusing as every patient from *group A* is matched to multiple patients from *group B*. So, do they choose the follow-up time of the control with shortest follow-up within a matched set? Or is this generally done in another way?

Comment: Propensity matching has a [large number of serious problems](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/propensity.html) and is highly discouraged.

Comment: I am aware propensity score matching (PSM) has important limitations, but I am trying to understand how these existing studies that applied 1:x PSM and pairwise-censoring did this.

Comment: Just beware that what these studies provided may not be trustworthy.  The first thing to check is whether the matching algorithm they used resulted in discarding more than 10% of the original observations.

Comment: Would you mind providing a reference for such a claim? My understanding is that this is totally unnecessary and not standard practice. Matching allows you to run the same analysis you would have run in the absence of matching but with mitigation of some confounding and reduction of model dependence. So matching should not require a different procedure from the analysis of an RCT. The main difference would be in estimation of the standard error, which should account for pair membership.

Comment: I do not claim that the analysis should be different in the case of matched data. I only ask how pairwise censoring works if you have multiple controls matched to one subject from the intervention group (as is often the case in PSM).